# How can I 'Do something' if protractor test case fails?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a test suite of around 1000 test cases, but sometimes if one test case fails due to some unclosed popup window, all of the subsequent test cases will also fail because the popup modal will not allow protractor to interact with page elements.(My app is that way)
So I want to create some condition such as i will refresh the page if a test case fails or I will go to my homepage link if test case fails as all tc's start from same starting point.
This will prevent all my subsequent test cases from failing. This method was called recovery scenario in QTP/UFT days.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing these kind of issue that if one test case fails subsequent all test cases will fail,Not sure if there is any recovery scenarios available in protractor  but I am using before all, after all, before each and after each to start my each test from a clean state. I have added a helper function to navigate to Home page and I call every time this function from before each.

[this is helpful link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing)

Comment: I use these too, as I have very large framework, I can start from same homepage but a refresh would work for me.